# schedule notifications and emails based on date and time limit in spring

Tags: java, spring, email, model-view-controller, alert

in my spring mvc application I need to notify users about their tasks and send them an email whenever the time limit is reached. How can I do that?

Comment: scope of answer is too wide better ask some point to point question like if you are getting some error, dont know how to do something with code etc

Answer (score 1):

1. [Spring Scheduling Docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html) - Use `@Scheduled(fixedDelay=..)` for occasional lookups or `@Scheduled(cron=..)` for more intricate trigger
2. The above scheduled operation will perform a DB lookup in a table where you have stored some timestamp. Then `now - timestamp` will be calculated to see whether it is breaching the configurable `threshold`
3. In that case `EmailService` takes over for user email lookup and email send operations